# Отлючить проверку протокола HTTPS для вебсокетов

Tags: nginx, golang, websocket, angular, https

Есть приложение Angular + Golang, которое запускается в докере. Пользователь подключается по **https**, но между клиентом и сервером **http**. **Nginx** также работает только с **http**. Проверка ***ssl сертификатов*** выполняется на отдельном сервере посредством reverse proxy и с докер контейнера нет возможности получить доступ к файлам сертификата. При попытке отправить запрос по вебсокету через протокол ***ws://host*** браузер блокирует запрос, т.к. требуется ***wss://host***.
Есть ли возможность отключить проверку протокола для возможности отправки запроса через ***ws://host***?

**Конфиг nginx**

````
upstream front {
  server web:4200;
}

upstream back {
  server api:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;    
    server_name <hostname>;    

    client_max_body_size       50m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://front;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://back/;
    }

    location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Origin <hostname>;

        proxy_pass http://front;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Origin <hostname>;

        proxy_pass http://back;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

    location ~ /\.  {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        deny all;
    }
}```
````

Comment: «Пользователь подключается по https, но между клиентом и сервером http» — это предложение выглядит как-то бредово. Пользователь — это и есть клиент, и если он подключается по https, значит между клиентом и сервером https таки есть. Из текста вопроса я так и не понял — в чём проблема пустить вебсокет через тот же самый https, который у пользователя уже есть? При чём тут отдельный сервер и докер?

Comment: Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы отправить сообщение в вебсокете через https, необходимо указать пути к ssl сертификатам в nginx. Но из контейнера нет возможности получить доступ к файлу сертификата, т.к. он расположен на другом сервере, который редиректит пользователя после проверки ssl сертификата в приложение.
По поводу клиента и пользователя.
Под клиентом имелся ввиду контейнер с angular, который общается с сервером по http, без использования ssl сертификатов.

Comment: Тогда каким чудом «пользователь подключается по https», если к сертификатам доступа нет? У меня не складывается целостного представления, как это всё у вас работает

Comment: Пользователь подлючается на основной сервер, на котором установлены ssl сертификаты. Затем выполняется внутренний редирект на приложение в докере, которое работает по http. Но в адресной строке пользователю отображается https.
Подобная инфраструктура настраивалась отдельно, поэтому нет возможности вынести сертификаты на этот же сервер по соображениям безопасности.

Comment: Ну, делайте точно такой же редирект для вебсокета да и всё?